# Changing match to allow null input in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some inherited code which is causing problems in Safari.

The problem comes from a few lines in the code that do things like this:

```
if ( ... && $("#element1").val().match(/regex/) && ...)
```

The javascript itself is programmatically generated.

The problem is that sometimes that $("#element1").val() returns null and I can't easily put a typeof check before it, because it needs to treat null as empty string.

The easiest (and manageable) solution would be either to create a nullmatch function and call that instead or to override the .match function itself. The new function would then check for null first and (if it is null) pass empty string to match instead of null.

I am not sure how to do either, or which would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would be better to either replace, or add to it (e.g.
>       `$("element1").val().nullmatch(/regex/)` or 
>       `$("element1").val().nullToEmpty().match(/regex/)`

That isn't really possible, because `.nullmatch` or `.nullToEmpty` would need to be a method on a possibly `null` value.

If you really want to write in this fashion, or it's easier for your backend to generate, then you could write a mini-plugin:

```
$.fn.valNullToEmpty = function() { return this.val() || ''; }

$("element1").valNullToEmpty().match(/regex/)
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't think of replacing val()!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `||` operator:

```
if ( ... && ($("#element1").val() || "").match(/regex/) && ...)
```

Basically, `foo || ""` will return `foo` if it's truthy, or the empty string if `foo` is falsy (`false`, `undefined`, `null`, empty string, `+0`, `-0` or `NaN`).

Comment: A good solution, but as per the other one, it's not trivial for me to surround $("#element1") and .val() as they are created separately in the original code, so I was looking to replace match or add to the chain.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
function nullString(str) {
    if (str === null) {
        return "";
    else {
        return str;
    }
```

So your if statement could become

```
if ( ... && nullString($("#element1").val()).match(/regex/) && ...)
```

Comment: The solution would work, but because of the way the javascript is generated, it's not trivial to surround the $("element1").val() as a whole statement. It would be better to either replace, or add to it (e.g. `$("element1").val().nullmatch(/regex/)` or `$("element1").val().nullToEmpty().match(/regex/)` )

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery docs for [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) state that it returns null when the element is select and no options are selected.

So using valHooks may help

```
var originalSelectHook;
if ($.valHooks.select) {
  originalSelectHook = $.valHooks.select.get;
}

$.valHooks.select = {
  get: function(elem) {
    var index = elem.selectedIndex;
    if (index == -1 || elem.options[index].disabled) {
       return "";
    }
    else {
      return originalSelectHook(elem)
    }
};
```

Code assumes that there is a existing hook for select